# How do I display mysql database datas in table vertically

Tags: php, html, mysql

i'm trying to display database datas in table format but i'm having issue in formating to display datas in table it's not displaying in correct order. i want to display datas vertically but it's displaying horizontally.

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">S.N.</th>
      <th scope="col">Title</th>
      <th scope="col">Grade</th>
      <th scope="col">Notice Date</th>
      <th scope="col">Actions</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
        <?php foreach ($result as $file): ?>
      <th scope="row"><?php echo $file['id']; ?><br/></th>
      <td><?php echo $file['title']; ?><br/></td>
      <td><?php echo $file['grade']; ?><br/></td>
      <td><?php echo $file['date']; ?><br/></td>
      <td><a href="admin/uploads/School/admissionform/<?php echo $file['name']; ?>"><i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i></a><br/></td>
        <?php endforeach;?>

    </tr>
    
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOPAe.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is only adding table *cells* to the same overall row, it's not adding table *rows*.  Move the `<tr>` tags into the loop:

```
<tbody>
<?php foreach ($result as $file): ?>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row"><?php echo $file['id']; ?><br/></th>
    <td><?php echo $file['title']; ?><br/></td>
    <td><?php echo $file['grade']; ?><br/></td>
    <td><?php echo $file['date']; ?><br/></td>
    <td><a href="admin/uploads/School/admissionform/<?php echo $file['name']; ?>"><i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i></a><br/></td>
  </tr>
<?php endforeach;?>
</tbody>
```